# Oracle Hibernate mapping - NUMBER(4,0)

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle11g

I have the id of a column as `NUMBER(4,0).` I have tried using Integer, Short, BigDecimal and BigInt for the type of the id instance variable. 
I got different errors showing that the type used was not correct.

I am using `Oracle 11g`.

```
Wrong column type in MyDatabase.schema for column id. Found: number, expected: smallint
```

Comment: post your hibernate mapping xml/entity class using annotation

Comment: `BigDecimal` works for `Number(10,3)`. Not sure why it shouldn't work for `Number(4,0)`.

Answer (score 1):

In oracle `NUMBER(4,0)` means a number with total number of digits 4.

In java types not exactly available identical primitive data type... The nearest datatypes are:

- byte: -128 to 127 (3 digits)
- short: -32,768 to 32,767 (5 digits)

In this case I recommend to use the smaller one (byte), to avoid overflow the oracle variable limit in java side.

So the hibernate column definition looks like this:

```
@Column(name = "NFOURCOL", columnDefinition = "NUMBER(4,0)")
public Byte getNfour() {
  return nfour;
}
```

The `columnDefinition = "NUMBER(4,0)"` part do the trick, it's tell to hibernate what is the expected definition  of the column in oracle side.